# Blazor Web Assembly with Azure AAD and Custom authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, custom-authentication

I want to implement two authentication mechanism in my Blazor web assembly application (Azure AD and Custom Authentication). i.e. User can either login via Azure AD or he can go for Custom Authentication. When I register both Custom AuthenticationStateProvider and AddMsalAuthentication in program.cs and try to login via AAD that time I am getting below error.

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__0`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=5.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=5.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal.Models.MsalProviderOptions, Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal, Version=5.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].<AddRemoteAuthentication>b__0_0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__1(ServiceProviderEngineScope p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent(Type componentType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

Below is my Main method of Program.cs

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
            builder.Services.AddMicrosoftGraphClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");

            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthStateProvider>();

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
                options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
            }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState,
                RemoteUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<AuthStateProvider>());
            builder.Services.AddOptions();
            //builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

            builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
            builder.Services.AddBlazorTable();
            builder.Services.AddMatBlazor();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<LabelPrintingHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<DataAccessHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<DataUploadHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<StoreProfileHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<EventLogHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClientAppConfigService, ClientAppConfigService>();

            builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClientInfoService, ClientInfoService>();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Below is my Custom AuthStateProvider class:

```
public class AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage;

        public AuthStateProvider(ISessionStorageService sessionStorage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var bonus = await GetBonusAsync();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bonus))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(await Task.FromResult(new ClaimsIdentity())));
            }

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, bonus),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Client authentication");
            
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        }
        
        private async Task<string> GetBonusAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var base64BonusNumber = await _sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>(Base64Encode("bonus"));
                return Base64Decode(base64BonusNumber);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Please help if you can suggest any way to implement both (azure AD and custom authentication) authentication in blazor webassembly

Comment: Hi @Reishabh, did you get anywhere with this?  I tried creating a brand new WASM project using MS Identity AddMsalAuthentication for auth from template and it ran Ok.  I then added the most basic CustomAuthenticationStateProvider and got the error message that you encountered.  I'm wondering if this isn't supported, or it is a bug.  I couldn't find any documentation either way and no examples that used both MSAL and CustomAuthenticationStateProvider..

Answer (score 1):

I raised this error as an issue on github dotnet / aspnetcore

[Blazor WASM MSAL with CustomAuthenticationStateProvider Gives Error](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44692)

The advice given is as follows:

> If you want to use the built-in MSAL support and customize how the user is defined you need to create your own AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-the-user
>
> It is possible to create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider, but
> doing so requires extending AuthenticationService and registering all
> its implementations in the DI container, which is not trivial.